# File upload issue using ajax in laravel 6

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel, laravel-5

I am trying to store pdf along with other input value using ajax in laravel 6. Here I did not use form html element .
It shows **Call to a member function getClientOriginalExtension() on null** .
**How can I send file ?**

In Blade

```
<input name="phone" type="text" class="form-control phone">
<input type="file" name="my_doc" accept="application/pdf" class="my_doc" id="my_doc">

<button type="button" class="store_new"> Save </button>

$(document).on('click', '.store_new', function () {
   var phone= $('.phone').val();
   var my_doc= $('.my_doc').val();

   $.ajax({
        url: '{{ url('/admin/add-new-item') }}',
        type: "POST",
        headers: {
             'X-CSRF-TOKEN': '{{ csrf_token() }}'
        },
        data: {
            phone: phone,
            my_doc: my_doc,
        },
        success: function (response) {
                   
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {

        }
     });
});
```

In controller

```
use File;

public function store(Request $request)
{
  
    $image = $request->file('my_doc');
    $new_name = rand() . '.' . $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
    $image->move(public_path('final_doc'), $new_name);

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to send your payload as formData or convert your object to formData and pass the actual file

i.e.

```
let formData = new FormData()
formData.append('phone', $('.phone').val() )
// Attach file
formData.append('my_doc', $('input[type=file]')[0].files[0])


$.ajax({
    .
    .
    .
    data: formData,
    .
    .
    .
});
```

or you can use [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/object-to-formdata)

Also, on your laravel controller make sure the document is not null before processing it so you won't get any php error.

```
$doc = $request->file('my_doc');

if ( $doc ) {
    // process your file
}
```

Comment: Thanks but still getting null . dd($request->file('my_doc')) ;

Comment: `console.log` your payload before sending it to laravel to verify its there, obviously, you are not sending an actual file

Comment: append
: 
ƒ append()
length
: 
2
name
: 
"append"

Comment: Can you please tell me how can I check file not empty before ajax call  ? Because it's not mandatory

Comment: you can simply do `if ( $('#my_doc')[0].files )`  or `if ( $('#my_doc')[0].files.lenght > 0 )`